# I want to create a library for lora on renesas synergy s7 board

Tags: lora, lorawan

I am using s7 Renesas synergy board and I want to set up a node that can connect to the Lora gateway that is already set up. eventually, I want to create a basic library for this board.
My question is, what is the basic function that I need to use from the LMIC library and what changes do I need to make to those functions in order for them to work for my board.

I already included the LMIC library but it is very confusing to understand all of it and I can't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic version of the question is: how to port LMIC to my s7 Renesas synergy board?

LMIC has already split up the higher level LMIC code and the HAL implementation for the platform. Porting LMIC to the s7 would involve implementing all the functions defined inside the `hal.c` and implementing these functions with the hardware dependent HAL from Renesas. (You must also take all configuration parameters and tweak those to fit your board)

- A basic starting point would involve taking the [Arduino LMIC](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic) created by Matthijs Kooijman.
- Alternative starting point with the LMIC from
  [things4u](https://github.com/things4u/LoRa-LMIC-1.51)
- Here is an [example of a
  port](https://github.com/mcci-catena/ibm-lmic) based on the STM32
  platform (also an ARM platform with familiar naming conventions)

It would be the easiest to take one of these ports and empty out the implementations and fill it in with your own.

Comment: Thanks for this other library shares I am currently working on Arduino LMIC library by kooijman but thanks for the other libraries aswell it really helped understand more.

Comment: I have one more question but I don't know if I should ask here in the comment or should I make a new post for it so I will add it here first.

Comment: If it is a separate question: you should open a new question. If it is a clarification: ask it here. Also please feel free to upvote or even accept the answer if it helped your or fixed your problem.

Comment: In hal.cpp there are functions named hal_ticks and hal_waituntil what are these functions doing....... and hal_disableIRQ and hal_enableIRQ what IRQs are we disabling or enabling using these functions or are these just so that no interrupts can interfere while this specific code is running?

Comment: It seems that that would be an unique question about Arduino LMIC. Please create a new one with these code snippets included.